# .ogg-files are not working on my website

Tags: audio, iis-7, asp-classic, ogg

". ogg" files will not play on my website. The browser displays a 404.3-error. It has probably something to do with the configuration of the server. When I asked the server administrator, he referred to http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config.aspx. But thats a guide that is intended for. NET users - and my website are made in classic ASP. How is the solution implemented in classic ASP - is it possible?
See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use IIS manager, which means you either need a remote desktop connection to your server or you need to get your server admin to do it for you.

Either way, instructions on how to add a mime type are here

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx